# High Resolution Image display in UIImageView

Tags: iphone, memory-management, crash, uiimageview

My Requirment is need to show the 4000 x 2000 image in UIImageView, but i displayed this image in UIImageView... I Received memory warning after that some navigation app crash.. Could anyone please suggest me how to get rid that problem.. And yes i dont want to resize that images

Answer (score 5):

You should use a [`CATiledLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html). See Apples [PhotoScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html) for a sample implementation.

Comment: My requirement to use ios 4..not able to run it.

Comment: CATiledLayer is available since iOS2, the worst bugs were fixed in iOS4. Only the example requires iOS6, but you don't have to copy the sample verbatim.

Answer (score 3):

try with  this code, it may solve your problem

```
     CGSize initialImageSize = userimage.frame.size;

     CGSize imageSize = userimage.image.size;
     CGFloat aspectRatio = imageSize.width / imageSize.height;

     CGRect imageFrame = userimage.frame;

     if (initialImageSize.width / aspectRatio <= initialImageSize.height) {
     imageFrame.size.width = initialImageSize.width;
     imageFrame.size.height = imageFrame.size.width / aspectRatio;
     } else {
     imageFrame.size.height = initialImageSize.height;
     imageFrame.size.width = imageFrame.size.height * aspectRatio;
     }
     userimage.frame = imageFrame;
```

where userimage is `UIImageView`  where you load your image.

Comment: Requirment is that need to display image in UIImageView without cropping without adjusting... just show it whatever size of the UIImage

Comment: you have to resize image in proper ratio ,other wise your application gets crash. your image size is 4000,2000. it's too big size.